# Too many missing records when using Export geoprocessing tool in ArcGIS Pro

Tags: arcgis-pro, feature-layer, arcgis-enterprise

I am using ArcGIS Pro ver 3.1 and 2.9.3; GIS Enterprise 10.9.1; HANA database version 2.00.059.04.1655794895 (fa/hana2sp05). Database feature class are all branch versioned, replica enabled.

When trying to export features from line feature class in ArcGIS Pro using export geoprocessing tool only **503,267** are copied over to new feature class out of **7,663,528** records.

We tried various ways to find the root cause. We **re-versioned** the our utility dataset, still the issue persist.
We did a expensive statement **trace** on HANA studio and extracted the query used by the application ArcGIS Pro to get that. when we ran the same query on the base table it did return 7,663,528 records.

Same issue is happening when we create a mobile geodatabase from the create replica function from the REST API of the feature layer service.

Any suggestions or solutions?

Comment: A query on the base table means little unless it has been compressed. Bad geometry or an invalid data value could cause export to fail. Re-versioning can corrupt your database; I hope you did this in close cooperation with Esri Tech Support.  There a ton of missing critical details here, and this Q&A model doesn't really support the round-trips necessary for problem-solving on this. Which is why this is really a Tech Support issue.